# Degbug toolbar does not appear in symfony 3.3 in dev environment in my website

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, toolbar, profiler

I am using symfony 3.3. But i cannot see the debug toolbar(_profiler) even though I did which google says correctly.
I went to _profiler route also.But it says 404 error.
Can someone help me?

Following is my config.yml and config_dev.yml

**config.yml**

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }

parameters:
    locale: en
framework:
   profiler:
       collect: false
   secret:    "%secret%"
   router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
   form:            ~
   csrf_protection: ~
   validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
   #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
   templating:
        engines: ['twig','php']
   default_locale:  "%locale%"
   usted_proxies: ~
   session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration    /framework.html#handler-id
   handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
   save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
   fragments:       ~
   http_method_override: true
   assets: ~
   php_errors:
        log: true
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
swiftmailer:
        transport: "%mailer_transport%"
        host:      "%mailer_host%"
        username:  "%mailer_user%"
        password:  "%mailer_password%"
        spool:     { type: memory }
kms_froala_editor:
         language: 'en_ca'
```

**config_dev.yml**

```
imports:
- { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }


web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    position: bottom
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: [!event]
        console:
            type:   console
            bubble: 
            verbosity_levels:
                VERBOSITY_VERBOS : NOTICE
                VERBOSITY_DEBUG : DEBUG
                VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE : NOTICE
            channels: [!event, !doctrine]
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server 

configuration
        firephp:
            type:   firephp
            level:  info
        chromephp:
            type:   chromephp
            level:  info
```

Comment: did you check if a) your [webserver is correctly configured](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) and  b) have a valid html document with a `<body>` tag in your view?

Comment: In my web server there is no php.ini file. Shoud i create it in my public html and turn on xdebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send response that has not correct html structure, you do not see debug toolbar. You should have the following content in response to see debug toolbar:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you see 404, that means that you has not controller for this route, you can see your routes by:

```
php bin/console debug:route
```

Or your server is closed. You can start them by command:

```
php bin/console server:run
```

Anyway you should read about error status codes. It will save you a lot of time:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. whe i run "php bin/console debug:route" it shows "_profiler" route in the terminal and  My web server is not localhost. it is hosted in a a2hosting.  so i think "php bin/console server:run" command is  not essential.    My template   extends base.html.twig and it has {%block body %} {% endblock %} So it is still not working.

Comment: if it hosted, so try comment lines `header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');` and `exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');` in your `web/app_dev.php` file and type in browser `your_domain_or_ip/app_dev.php`

Comment: When remove that lines of code, i  can go to the _profiler/ route. But still i cannot see the debug toolbar. Now i can see the error messages when i route in this way "localhost/sf3/app_dev.php/"

Comment: Can you show what kind of error you see? Typically when you deploy project there is problem with permissions to catalog var. http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Comment: Anyway, what was the reason of problem?

Comment: The reason was i turned off debug mode in app_dev.php file.